# Streaming Uploads To PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, stream, websocket

I am using `PHP` to upload files. On the server side of the action that gets called after the upload completes is simply:

```
<?php
     print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

Which outputs something like:

```
Array
(
  [file] => Array
    (
        [name] => space_needlenever_lonely_alone.mp3
        [type] => audio/mp3
        [tmp_name] => /srv/www/uploads/php1TCIY9
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 3768714
    )

)
```

The problem is I don't want to store files on the server disk `( /srv/www/uploads/php1TCIY9)` at all. I actually want to store files into `MongoDB` using `GridFS`. Is there a way to stream directly into PHP without storing the file on disk on the server first? Storing files on disk requires all kinds of headaches such as permissions, and php ini configurations regarding uploads.

A websocket connection would be awesome, if I can stream the binary data directly into the server side page without writing to disk.

Or, is it possible to interact with MongoDB from a JavaScript point of view (client side) and skip interacting with PHP?

Possible, or a pipe dream?

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP application is not even executed until the file upload is done.  Because of this, I believe this is impossible with PHP.

Comment: I am using this great JavaScript library for drag and drop support: http://www.github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop and it makes two `XHR` requests. The first looks like its client side http://pastie.org/4614156 the second XHR request is to the action PHP page.

Comment: @Justin, What you use client-side doesn't change the general mechanics of how and when your PHP code is executed.

Comment: It is possible, by streaming the binary data to PHP and reading the `php://input` stream - but this won't be treated as an HTTP upload, so you won't have access to the files in the `$_FILES` array.